# SQL Server MAXDOP tuning in Virtual Environment

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2, sql-server-2012

Been trying to research different best practices for SQL Server for our existing database to improve performance, and today stumbled on the Parallelism options. Unfortunately, it seems there's very conflicting opinions on how to configure MAXDOP in a Virtual Environment.

Currently running on AWS EC2 (r4.4xLarge) and SQL Server 2012 SP4.

Does it seem like tuning MAXDOP from 0 have significant performance impacts? And, is it accurate to set the Max Degree to the number of "virtual" cores the system has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't leave it to 0, because that means a plan could use ALL cores and then you could get a ton of CXPACKET waits. Remember that when plans go parallel, they aren't necessarily evenly distributed. So, some threads will finish quicker and have less work... then your stuck with CXPACKET waiting on the other threads to get done, and to recompile everything.

Also, it's real important to set the [cost threshold for parallelism away from the default](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/03/why-cost-threshold-for-parallelism-shouldnt-be-set-to-5/). This is what determines if your plan *can* go parallel (assuming it's not a serial plan). A low cost here means a small query could go parallel and it'd be faster to just use 1 thread.

I'd suggest these:

- [Brent thread configuring MAXDOP](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/configuring-parallelism/)
- Then check out [Kin's detailed answer on this subject](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36522/maxdop-setting-algorithm-for-sql-server) regarding logical and physical CPU count with regards to NUMA nodes
- Brent also touching on the [issue with CPU settings in virutalization](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/brent/sql-server-virtualization-get-your-hands-off-that-maxdop/)
- And to be official, [Microsoft's recommendation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2806535/recommendations-and-guidelines-for-the-max-degree-of-parallelism-confi)

Comment: Thanks for this scsimon! I actually read through Brent's Issues with CPU Settings and that's what lead me here to ask the question. Kin's script suggest (for my environment) to use a MAXDOP of 8, which would have been my starting place if Brent hadn't brought up the issues with Virtualized Environments.

A MAXDOP of 8 would mean a query could take up upwards of half my cores--rather than all of them. Sounds fantastic to me. It seems like the virtualization concern isn't as exact as I was thinking?

Comment: Well, it depends if you have control over your environment. What Brent was trying to drive home was that a Datacenter Admin / Network Admin / someone that isn't you could shift your virtual server and change the memory and CPU without you knowing (unless you were checking often) and thus, this could make your MAXDOP settings not be optimal. I'd go with 8 if you always expect to have more than 8 processors. If you expect to have less than that, then less obviously (like 4). Usually cores are taken away versus randomly given though. If you have > 8 cores leaving it at 0 isn't advised.

Comment: also, just wanted to mention again, check that cost threshold for parallelism setting. It's pretty important too. Also, for a smarter answer, post this on dba.stackexchange.com and just reference a link to this question. As you can see, that's where the DBA guru's hang out... i just stalk them heavily.

Comment: Given this is an EC2 instance, I have to assume I'll always have access do a designated number of cores, so it seems like either 8--to keep half of them free, or 4 to allow upwards of 4 parallel queries to run would make sense? I'm going to leave it at 8 for now and see what happens.

Any chance you could speak on properly configuring Cost Thresholds? I've set this DB's from 5 to 50 off the recommendation, but is there any clear way to know if it needs to be moved up or down from there?

Comment: A EC2! Well 4 won't be free... that is, it isn't like SQL Server picks 4 cores and says "uses these only" It just uses no more than 4 for any given query. It can use all 8 cores... just not 8 for a single query. So one query could use core 1-4, another use 2-6, another 1,3,6, and 8... etc. Regarding cost... that one is a lot harder and depends on your work load but this is one of those things you'd change... then measure different wait stats and tune from there to be more, or less.

Comment: And, remember, you can override the server setting in any query using the MAXDOP query hint... so if 1 query is bugging you, you can add MAXDOP(n) on the query and force that query to use this setting over the server.

Comment: Wanted to say thanks again scsimon for the clarification! My server has an intensely mixed workload, and I believe queries that didn't need to were often going parallel--and ones that really needed it were over paralleling.

Ran some tests on one of our well known lock everything up queries, and it ran minutes faster with no lock ups to other queries that we could tell.

Comment: That's awesome to hear @Devin! Performance tuning is the hardest thing to do IMHO. I think you'd like Dr. DeWitt's video on WHY it's so hard to get right, at least query optimization. https://youtu.be/RQfJkNqmHB4

Answer (score 0):

MAXDOP will only have an effect on parallelizable operations.  There are many things that can stop parallelization. IOW if the query can only use 1 processor, setting MAXDOP=64 won't make it any faster.

Comment: The database I'm working with is the back end of an MRP system, and deals with pretty drastically different queries. Is there any easy or concise way to see if parallelism is being utilized?

Comment: You have to look at the execution plan, query by query,  If you're on 2016 or up, you can use query store to help you.  that would make searching easier.  What I would do is take an example query that runs more than a few seconds run it with maxdop(1) and again with maxdop(8), look at the plan to see if it is parallel, if not, try to figure out what is in the way.

Comment: @Devin Look for serial plans, that means they are single threaded. There are also some DB maintenance tasks that are single threaded, like index reorgs.

Comment: Actually found a query here:
https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/07/25/sql-server-how-to-find-if-queries-are-run-in-parallel/

That outputs all parallel execution plans. I'm certainly seeing something, sounds like the only way to really confirm if increasing MAXDOP would be effective is just to try it?

Comment: @Devin Those could *still* go parallel if the cost threshold is low enough(see my answer below). Remember maxdop is only stating how many cores a query can use... so if you had 8 and maxdop was 0 or 8, it could use all 8. If you set it to 4, it could only use 4 cores. More on my answer below, especially regarding virtualization, but MAXDOP and Cost Threshold for Parallelism are two different, but related things.